# VB.Net Regex Licence Key

Tags: regex, vb.net

So i want to parse licence keys from some text (**mytext**).

All licence keys are in form of: `XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX` (X as random character)

I tried:

```
Dim findtext1 As String = "(?<=\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5})"
Dim myregex1 As String = mytext
Dim doregex1 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex1, findtext1)
Dim matches1 As String = ""
For Each match1 As Match In doregex1
    matches1 = matches1 + match1.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches1)
```

But no results have been found.

Comment: Why are you using `lookbehind` ? And what does your character class consists of ?

Comment: I don't understand you.

Comment: You wish to match`XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX` then why using `(?<=)` ? It's for zero width matching.

Comment: Then `(\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5})` is the answer?

Comment: Exactly ! Could be shortened depending on allowed characters. [check demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sgTSS/1/) But first you need to mention which characters are allowed ? Like  `\w` stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` stands. Are there more valid characters ?

Comment: I removed `?<=` and it works now, thank you!

Comment: @Stefan Try `((\w{5}-){4}\w{5})`

Comment: I believe you need to only match this string as a whole string. Then you need `"^\w{5}(?:-\w{5}){4}$"`. No idea why use `Regex.Matches` though.

Comment: @Rahul: In .NET,  `\w` stands for `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` by default. See what is [can match](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%7b5%7d-%5cw%7b5%7d-%5cw%7b5%7d-%5cw%7b5%7d-%5cw%7b5%7d&i=%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab-%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab-%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab-%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab-%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab%e0%b8%ab).

Answer (score 0):

> But no results have been found.

Problem with your regex `(?<=\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5})` is your are trying to match `zero-witdh` by using `(?<=..)` which is called `Positive Lookbehind`.

You should try with `^(\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5}-\w{5})$`.

To make it short there are various ways. Like some of them noted in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to *extract* those numbers from a larger text. Thus, you need to make the pattern a *consuming* one (that is, remove `(?<=` and final `)` that made your pattern an example of a positive lookbehind that only checks if a text matches a pattern, but does not put the matched text into the match value returned) and use *word boundaries* to avoid partial matches inside longer substrings (e.g. avoid matching `abc` with `a\wc` pattern  inside a `nabc45` string).

Here is the whole fixed code:

```
Dim findtext1 As String = "\b\w{5}(?:-\w{5}){4}\b"
Dim myregex1 As String = "ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345;FGHIJ-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345; ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-123456"
Dim doregex1 As MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(myregex1, findtext1)
Dim matches1 As String = ""
For Each match1 As Match In doregex1
    matches1 = matches1 + match1.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
Console.Write(matches1)
```

See the [VB.NET demo online](http://ideone.com/k0L82a). It prints

```
ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345
FGHIJ-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345
```

but not `ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-123456` (as the last chunks contains 6 digits).

**Pattern details**:

- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `\w{5}` - 5 word chars
- `(?:-\w{5}){4}` - exactly 4 occurrences of `-` followed with 5 word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cw%7b5%7d%28%3f%3a-%5cw%7b5%7d%29%7b4%7d%5cb&i=ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345%3bFGHIJ-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345%3b+ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-123456).

Note that in .NET `\w` matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`, that is, all Unicode letters and digits, so, if you only need to match ASCII chars, pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option:

```
Regex.Matches(myregex1, findtext1, RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
```

And  another note: if you do not need to match a `_`, you will need to tweak the pattern to exclude the `_` and add it to the word boundary:

```
(?<=\b|_)[^\W_]{5}(?:-[^\W_]{5}){4}(?=\b|_)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%7c_%29%5b%5e%5cW_%5d%7b5%7d%28%3f%3a-%5b%5e%5cW_%5d%7b5%7d%29%7b4%7d%28%3f%3d%5cb%7c_%29&i=ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345%3b_FGHIJ-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12345_%3b+ABCDE-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-12_45).